# The "talk to an expert" and "buy now" buttons are broken on the Tag Sponsorships page

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, sponsored-tags

The "talk to an expert" and "buy now" buttons at the bottom of https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise/solutions/tag-sponsorship are broken. They have a `href="#"` so you'd expect a JS click handler, but there aren't any.

The "talk to an expert" button at the top of the page does work, it links to https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise/contact-us1

Comment: [credit to zaq for noticing](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5710680#5710680)

Comment: error 404: expert not found

Comment: looks like that page is gon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These were pages that are being actively developed and weren't meant to be public yet. We've taken them down, but you'll be seeing them again in a few weeks.

If you were looking to find out more about tag sponsorships, you can go here for now: https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise

Comment: You have to state that you're shamelessly advertising before you shamelessly advertise. This is an internet policy ;)

Comment: The link is only to direct people that intended to find similar information about tag sponsorships in the pages that were taken down, not to further advertise.

Comment: I was just teasing

Comment: Whoops *puts silly hat back on* :)